# How to convert icon to bitmap in window phone?

Tags: windows-phone

Is there any way to convert icon(.ico) format to bitmap ?

I can not use

```
 icon.ToBitmap
```

in window phone ?

Comment: Do you need to do this at runtime? Otherwise, you should convert it beforehand.

Comment: You should take a look on the WriteableBitmap class http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap(v=vs.110).aspx